# How to know XCTestExpectation current fulfillment count

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, testing, xctest

In async tests is common, at least for me, to have to know the fulfilment count of an expectation to know how to assert.

For instance, a test to check this scenario:

1. Fetch data
2. After receiving first callback, assert if items are as expected
3. Fetch next page of items
4. Assert if items are as expected

```swift
    func testOne() {
        let expectData = expectation(description: "data")
        expectData.expectedFulfillmentCount = 2
        var expectDataFulfillmentCount = 0
        
        sut.data = {
            expectData.fulfill()
            expectDataFulfillmentCount += 1
            
            if expectDataFulfillmentCount == 1 {
                XCTAssertEqual(sut.numberOfItems, 3)
                sut.fetchNextPage()
            } else if expectDataFulfillmentCount == 2 {
                XCTAssertEqual(sut.numberOfItems, 6)
            }
        }

        sut.fetch()

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 0.1, handler: nil)
    }
```

I am not happy with this pattern. I know I can slightly change how I assert when having expectations, this way:

```swift
    func testTwo() {
        let expectFirstData = expectation(description: "firstData")
        let expectSecondData = expectation(description: "secondData")
        
        sut.data = {
            if sut.numberOfItems == 3 {
                expectFirstData.fulfill()
                sut.fetchNextPage()
            } else if sut.numberOfItems == 6 {
                expectSecondData.fulfill()
            }
        }

        sut.fetch()

        wait(for: [expectFirstData, expectSecondData], timeout: 0.1, enforceOrder: true)
    }
```

But I don't like this neither because then I am not asserting (there is no `XCTAssert`), I am just fulfilling expectations and then loosing the capacity to easily identify why and where the test failed. This pattern, though, is perfect for expectations over boolean values, like this one:

```swift
    func testThree() {
        let truePerformingOperationExpect = expectation(description: "truePerformingOperationExpect")
        let falsePerformingOperationExpect = expectation(description: "falsePerformingOperationExpect")
        
        sut.performingOperation = { fetching in
            if fetching {
                truePerformingOperationExpect.fulfill()
            } else {
                falsePerformingOperationExpect.fulfill()
            }
        }
        
        sut.fetch()

        wait(for: [truePerformingOperationExpect, falsePerformingOperationExpect], timeout: 0.1, enforceOrder: true)
    }
```

For me, this could be easily solved if I can get the current fulfilment count of an expectation, it would clean up the test a lot and I would have both of best worlds. Is it possible? Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up subclassing `XCTestExpectation`:

```
class CountedFulfillmentTestExpectation: XCTestExpectation {
    private(set) var currentFulfillmentCount: Int = 0

    override func fulfill() {
        currentFulfillmentCount += 1
        super.fulfill()
    }
}
```